# simulated driving video game using machine

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

I'm gong to make a video game and need help on how to start .
what is the tools that i need to make a car games with driving car simulator like games that we play with coins ? and what is the name of this car simulator machine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to study up on electronics if you want to head down this road.

There is no "car driving simulator" kit. It would need to be built from the ground up.

In short, you need to learn to crawl before you can walk.

Study up on game development and electronics before going down this path.

Comment: if i will hire a team to make this game for me ? what are the members qualifications needed ?

Comment: @AmarOmarAshour At least one member with PhD in CompSci, at least two members with a degree in management, one mathematician, one secretary, and if you're having incredible expectations, then a *software developer* may come handy as well.

Comment: @AmarOmarAshour I hope you didn't take that seriously.

Comment: okay why did you say it if you wanna me not to take it seriously ?

Comment: Amar: It will take a lot of money to build something like this. There are contractors out there that have much more experience if you'd like to pursue it further but be prepared, it will cost hundreds of thousands of US dollars to develop. There was a local company that built race simulators from the ground up. They used Cyberdome Technology I believe. A quick search of google will link to their website.

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk You're drastically over-estimating the costs of something like this.
Sure, to do it from scratch, creating the circuit boards and doing the research would be in the many thousands... But there is absolutely no reason you need that. A standard PC embedded in a box, with an arduino communicating via serial ports to the PC serving as a coin counter, it's fairly easy. 

That said, that fact someone needed to ask this in such a way means they probably lack the capability to do it. Electronics and game development are a must...

Comment: It isn't the hardware that would cost the majority of the money, it would be the labor costs from the engineers and game developers that would send this project into that price. If the poster was competent and did everything himself, this project could be done for less than 10k, probably less than 5k. Start hiring out and you're going to have to be prepared to drop major coin.

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk You're right. I did consider it as though he'd be doing all the work himself. Hardware would be less than $1,000 for any reasonable set up, but man-hours are by far the biggest expense.

Comment: this project is governmental not personal not a game for fun it will be used for some other issue and it's budget will be more than 1,000,000$ 
thanks all for help